# Steam-powered dirigibles in the late 17th to early 18th century

Tags: alternate-history, airships, pre-industrial

I want steam powered dirigibles in my world around the year 1700. As this is an alternate world, a new gas with the same essential properties as Hydrogen, apart from the whole exploding aspect seems doable. I still need these things powered though. It seems easy enough to have someone come up with a Watt like compressor earlier, but does anyone have any thoughts on how to make a vacuum steam engine plausible?  In my world, Europe is altered.  Russia is the great power, challenged by France and Germany.

Comment: What is a "vacuum steam engine"? What is a "Watt compressor"? And anyway, in a world where there exists a gas as light as hydrogen but which is not hydrogen *anything* is possible. (Nitpicking: such a world would be extremely unlike Earth -- it has different physics. *Nothing would be even remotely similar to Earth.*)

Comment: "[...]a new gas with the same essential properties as Hydrogen, apart from the whole exploding aspect[...]"  --> Helium, maybe?

Comment: Hello Andy!  We occasionally get questions that are basically, "how do I justify the faster development of X?"  This is almost always possible, but it depends on how much of the detail you really need.  Most Steampunk (which your story appears to be) simply "makes it so" and ignores the "how we got here" part.  If you need the details, technology is a pyramid and any one tech requires a lot of discovery and experience to justify it.  You'd need to move up the discovery and use of coal as a fuel source, metalurgy, mechanics, milling, machining, just to name a few. What, then, is your real goal?

Comment: You will also need easy heliographs to communicate ground-to-air, early telegraphy to transmit weather reports, some form of powerful portable lamps for spotlighting and marking darkened landing-fields, and fast-windlasses for reeling in ships quickly before they get destroyed by a shear. Not-very-severe weather destroyed large numbers of 20th-century dirigibles.

Comment: @NofP: Helium most definitely does not have the same essential properties as hydrogen. About the only similarity between them is that they are both very light; everything else is massively different.

Comment: @AlexP thank you Mr.Obvious, but what other properties could be used to make an airship with a non-explosive Hydrogen?

Comment: @NofP: The question explicitly says "essential properties". If the querent would have been interested only in the density of the gas they would have said "as light as".

Comment: @AlexP  as usual, I'd let the OP answer that, no?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! I'm happy to use Unobtanium, but as one of the central characters is the designer of a revolutionary new airship, I figure I need to be able to make my McGuffin somewhat more plausible than I otherwise would in Steampunk.

Comment: I only stumbled on this site yesterday and have been lost in it ever since. What a wonderful place this is. I certainly owe Willk a virtual beer already!

Answer (score 3):

**Ultrastrong film.**

Vacuum engines are kind of puny.  They can use 1 atmosphere pressure maximum to work.  The main piece of tech needed for a sweet steam engine is metallurgical tech capable of making a boiler and containing the steam pressure and letting it out to do work.  Many atmospheres of pressure accumulate in the boiler and you can use that to do serious work, like powering a train.  But it is metal, so the boiler is heavy and thus less than ideal for an airship.

In your world the people can make a film that is super strong and very light.  Also fireproof.   Maybe it is made from the bodies of sky jellyfish that fall to earth.  Of course my shorts are made of that stuff because it is also more or less see-through and my underwear has very funny prints.  But you can make your sky vessels from it.

Here is le plus awesome: **you use the float balloon as the boiler!**  Deflated, the balloon is full of water.  Heat it up and it fills with steam.  At maximal size it occupies more volume than the same volume of air, and so is buoyant.  But you can keep heating it.  It won't get bigger because this film doesn't stretch, but the steam gets hotter and hotter and the pressure rises higher and higher.

You do not need a new element besides hydrogen; @AlexP will stop grimacing.  All you need is some unobtanium film and then you can play with physics.

Benefits
1:  Steam engine tech.  You can release high pressure steam from the balloon to do work on your airship.  Propellers of course, or some other powered means of propulsion you dream up.  Also steam cannons, and fast-cooking stew, and you can press your uniforms to look snazzy.  Also, if you really crank the pressure up, you can release a burst of steam and propel the ship like a rocket engine.  Fold up the propellors before you do that because they will slow you down.

2:  If you run out of water your balloon will still work with air.  You will be more buoyant because air is lighter but you have become a hot air balloon.  You can still release the hot air to do work, like steam.

3;  Balloon spinnaker.  If you have a lot of pressure and suddenly inflate a second balloon you will suddenly get a lot of lift.  Your airship balloons can launch like helicopters or surge higher into the sky to avoid anti-aircraft guns.

4: The film is transparent, so if you (are evil) and want to put people in the balloon you will be able to see them swimming around in there.  This could be useful for the mwa-ha-ha factor because you will have to figure out some way to get the captives out before it gets too hot in there.